# Why is img Outline messing up Google Maps divs

Tags: css, google-maps

I'm setting up a map with Google for a website. I have an outline set for images though and this messes up the map. Anyone know why that is? Is it a bug?

## CSS

```
#pictures img {
    outline: 6px solid #333; /* <-- This messes up Maps */
}
#map_canvas {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div id="pictures">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8R3Mz/)

Comment: Google maps is a grid of multiple images, not 1 image, based on your CSS, the outline will be applied to ALL img tags in the pictures div

Comment: I solved the issue but my question is why the outline is applied to `div`s. I don't see any images in the outlined divs in maps.

Comment: If you expand out the nodes fully in chrome dev tools, you should see `img` tags.  I tried in Firebug, but can not see any `img` tags, maybe that is why.

Comment: @Bryan Yes, I expanded them in devtools, I did not find many `img` tags (only the logo and such)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your targeting all img that are children/grandchildren of #pictures

add this:

```
#map_canvas img {
  outline: 0px none transparent; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify that you don't want the `img` in the canvas to have a border.

Try this:

```
#map_canvas img {
    outline: 0px none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `C` is `CSS` stands for `cascade`

```
#map_canvas img { outline: none; }
```